# Matlab executes the first statement even if is false

Tags: matlab, if-statement, false-positive

I have the following function in matlab. I am trying to shuffle a matrix. But somehow matlab keeps executing the code from if even if the statement should go to else. And when it comes to else I have to put some aditional code, even if all it does is ***i+1*. It is normal for matlab or  am I missing something?

```
function magic_matrix = magicsquare1(matrix,n)
magic_matrix=ones(n,n)*(-1);
i=3-1;
j=4+1;

for ki=1:n
for kj=1:n
    if(i<1)
        i=n;
    end
    if(j>n)
        j=1;
    end
    if magic_matrix(i,j) == -1

        magic_matrix(i,j)=matrix(ki,kj);
        %X = sprintf('i=%d j=%d',i,j);
        %disp(X)
        i=i-1;
        j=j+1;
    else
        i=i+2;
        j=j-1;
        if(i>n)
            i=1;
        end
        if(j<1)
            j=n;
        end
        magic_matrix(i,j)=matrix(ki,kj);
       % X = sprintf('i=%d / j=%d',i,j);
        %disp(X)
        i=i-1;
        j=j+1;
    end
end
end
```

Comment: Your `magic_matrix` is all -1, so the `if` condition is always true.

Comment: I am trying to fill the matrix wich contains -1 with the elements from matrix. it enters in  else, but after executing the code from if.

Comment: Did you try to put a breakpoint and debug it? keep track of all the variables, and see where it fails to do what you expect.

Comment: Yes I did it with, but I cannot still figure it out why it keeps entering in if and then in else, even if my position in matrix is filled with a number different from -1.

Comment: Are you saying it goes into if block then immediately after it goes into else? I ran your code just now and didn't see that happening.

Comment: 'A=[17 24 1 8 15; 23 5 7 14 16; 4 6 13 20 22; 10 12 19 21 3; 11 18 25 2 9]'        This is my input matrix, and this should be the output:                                     'B= [24 14 4 19 9;7 22 12 2 17;20 10 25 15 5;3 18 8 23 13;11 1 16 6 21]' . And yes it goes into the _if_  block and then in else.